# PHP Forms Verification After Submit

Tags: php, forms, session, form-submit, isset

can anyone fix my code, i have two problem :

1/ if i use info.php directly i can see button submit (need to fix this by condition, so each time i use info.php without submit i must be redirected to another page or same page with link"click here befor submite" )

2/ when i refresh page i can always see bouton submit after clicking on link "click here befor submite" (i want destroy session, each time the page is reloaded i want see link not button submit) thank you very much

Index.php

```
    <html>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'submit')) {

    header('location: info.php');
}               

?> 
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['submit'])==1) {
?>  
<form method="get" action="index-1.php">
<br>
<?php
}
 else {
?>
<form method="get" action="info.php">
<?php 
} 
?>
<br>
<font color ="red">
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com"><font color ="black">*</font> text</a></br><br></h2>
    <hr /></font>
<h2><font color ="red">1.</font>Enter Your Personal Facebook profil URL : <input name="id" placeholder="https://www.facebook.com/YourName"/ size="45"/></h2><br>

</br>
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['submit'])==1) {
?>  
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="==>submit<==" id="submit" />
<?php
}
 else {
?>
<center><strong><a href="info.php">Click Here Before Submit </a></center></strong>

<?php 
} 
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

> info.php

```
   <?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['submit'] =1;
header('location: index.php');
?>
```

Comment: I can tell you right now, you're outputting before header in your first piece of code. Start the session above your html tags. Plus, you're using GET in your form's method, but mixing in a POST in `if (isset($_GET['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'submit'))` so there's another stick in your front wheel. Visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and use that in your code.

Comment: Then you have `if (isset($_SESSION['submit'])==1)` another stick. You need to check if it's set, AND if it equals "1" seperately, not the way you're doing it now, all rolled up into one. Add `exit;` after each header also.

Comment: thank you very much Fred -ii ^^ im not so familiar with php i tried more then 1 week to fix :( if only someone can add or delet what i did(mistake) it will help me really alot of thanks again

Comment: TBH, I don't quite know what to do with your code, because I don't know what you're trying to do. Try `if (isset($_GET['submit']) && ($_GET['submit'] == 'submit'))` for your first conditional, `if (isset($_SESSION['submit']) && $_SESSION['submit'] ==1)` for the second, and `if (isset($_SESSION['submit']))` for the third. Just play around for those if something goes a bit haywire. But, you get the gist of it.